# How to do fully connected batch norm in PyTorch?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, batch-normalization

`torch.nn` has classes `BatchNorm1d`, `BatchNorm2d`, `BatchNorm3d`, but it doesn't have a fully connected BatchNorm class? What is the standard way of doing normal Batch Norm in PyTorch?

Comment: what makes you think these layer are not fully connected?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out. `BatchNorm1d` can also handle Rank-2 tensors, thus it is possible to use `BatchNorm1d` for the normal fully-connected case.

So for example:

```
import torch.nn as nn


class Policy(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, num_inputs, action_space, hidden_size1=256, hidden_size2=128):
    super(Policy, self).__init__()
    self.action_space = action_space
    num_outputs = action_space

    self.linear1 = nn.Linear(num_inputs, hidden_size1)
    self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size1, hidden_size2)
    self.linear3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size2, num_outputs)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_size1)
    self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_size2)

def forward(self, inputs):
    x = inputs
    x = self.bn1(F.relu(self.linear1(x)))
    x = self.bn2(F.relu(self.linear2(x)))
    out = self.linear3(x)


    return out
```

Comment: This may not be related to machine learning but shouldn't the super call be like `super(Policy, self).__init__()` instead of `super(Policy2, self).__init__()`? In Python3 it can even be simplified to just `super().__init__()`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `F.relu(self.bn1(self.linear1(x)))`

Answer (score 11):

The BatchNorm1d normally comes before the ReLU, and the bias is redundant, so

```
import torch.nn as nn

class Policy(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, num_inputs, action_space, hidden_size1=256, hidden_size2=128):
    super(Policy2, self).__init__()
    self.action_space = action_space
    num_outputs = action_space

    self.linear1 = nn.Linear(num_inputs, hidden_size1, bias=False)
    self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size1, hidden_size2, bias=False)
    self.linear3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size2, num_outputs)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_size1)
    self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_size2)

def forward(self, inputs):
    x = inputs
    x = F.relu(self.bn1(self.linear1(x)))
    x = F.relu(self.bn2(self.linear2(x)))
    out = self.linear3(x)

    return out
```

Comment: batch norm should be after the relu as per this study: https://github.com/ducha-aiki/caffenet-benchmark/blob/master/batchnorm.md